# Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: method not allowed (405)"

Tags: iphone

I am using `AFNetworking` for Web services. It is working fine on `NSURLConnection`. It gives error using `AFNetworking`.

Here is my code:

```
 AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager POST:@"" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Succes");
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                            message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }];
```

This is the error I receive:

```
Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: method not allowed (405)" UserInfo=0x1e86b390 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://..............url.........., AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: method not allowed (405)}.
```

Can you please help for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your API is RestFul then you want to request using http. Use Below code may be it's helpful for you. Please let us know your comments.

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *post =[dict JSONRepresentation];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)[postData length]];

[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

//Add your request object to an AFHTTPRequestOperation
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request] ;
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

     NSString *response = [operation responseString];
     NSLog(@"response: %@",response);

 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);
 }];

//call start on your request operation
[operation start];
```