# Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: method not allowed (405)"

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking for downloading files on the server.But it gives a 405 error.
Here is my code,my own encapsulated  method:

```
+(id)download:(NSString *)url progress:(void(^)(CGFloat downloadRate)) downloadProgressBlock completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))completionHandler {
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [[self defaultAFManager] downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {
    downloadProgressBlock(downloadProgress.fractionCompleted);
} destination:^NSURL * _Nonnull(NSURL * _Nonnull targetPath, NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response) {
    NSString *filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject];
    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, NSURL * _Nullable filePath, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    completionHandler(error);
}];
[downloadTask resume];
return downloadTask;
```

}

This is the error I receive:
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: method not allowed (405)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: method not allowed (405)

Why? Can you please help for this.

Comment: maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789353/error-domain-afnetworkingerrordomain-code-1011-request-failed-method-not-allo